# How does DNS TTL work in chained CNAME configurations?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, ttl

I have a DNS config that looks something like this:

```
www.example.com                 600  IN   CNAME prod.myzone.l2.company.example
prod.myzone.l2.company.example      600  IN   CNAME ssl-endpoint-12345.hostcorp.example
ssl-endpoint-12345.hostcorp.example 60   IN   A     192.0.2.4
```

So the first two CNAME records in the chain have a TTL of 10 minutes, and the final A record has a TTL of 1 minute

The `prod.myzone.l2.company.example` CNAME does regional load-balancing between multiple endpoints, and is automatically updated if my DNS provider determines that the current endpoint is unhealthy.  For this reason, I would like to propagate changes to the `prod.myzone.l2.company.example` CNAME as quickly as possible.

If I wanted to reduce overall TTL that clients see when `prod.myzone.l2.company.example` changes, is it sufficient to only reduce the TTL of the `prod.myzone.l2.company.example` record, or do I also need to reduce the TTL on the `www.example.com` record as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TTL` for `CNAME` records does not work in any way differently than other records.

Let us imagine a recursive resolver through which the above goes.
It then fills its cache with:

- `www.example.com CNAME` valid for 600s
- `prod.myzone.l2.company.example CNAME` valid for 600s
- `ssl-endpoint-12345.hostcorp.example A` valid for 60s

If someone later query `ssl-endpoint-12345.hostcorp.example A` directly, then the 60s TTL applies.

But if the query comes for `www.example.com`, then the resolver will see it doesn't have an `A` record, but a CNAME and then reuse all of the above.

66s (for example) after the above, `www.example.com` is still in the resolver cache, but `ssl-endpoint-12345.hostcorp.example A` won't be anymore so the resolver will have to do a new DNS query to get that data, and cache it.

Comment: extrapolating from your answer: - if I set the intermediate `prod.myzone.l2.company.example` CNAME to 60s, clients will resolve `www.example.com` to the new `A` record within 60 seconds if `prod.myzone.l2.company.example` is updated?

Comment: @DrewShafer Yes. I recommend you set up a fake zone, similar to that, and just test things in your use case, to make sure it behaves as you need. You can install `unbound` or another local resolver and use it for your tests so that you can control its cache content. This would be a better result that anything that can be written here :-)

Comment: I can set up new zones pretty easily to test - thanks for the answer!